# Ant design: stopPropagation does not stop click from bubbling

Tags: antd

I’d like to display something like this in Ant Design:

[image]

to add a custom number of elements in a list. The problem for now is that when I click on the `+/-` buttons, the click is forwarded to the button, that gets clicked. I tried to use:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();e.preventDefault()
```

but it does not work. Any idea?

**MWE:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Planning</title>

    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/antd@4.16.13/dist/antd.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/antd@4.16.13/dist/antd.min.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="planning"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
      const { useState } = React;

      const { Button, InputNumber } = antd;
      const AddElements = ({...props}) => {
        const [nbEmployee, setNbEmployee] = React.useState(3);
        const handleAdd = (e) => {
          alert("You should NOT see me if you just clicked +");
        };
        return <Button onClick={handleAdd} type="primary">
          Add <InputNumber min={1} value={nbEmployee} onChange={setNbEmployee} onClick={e => {e.stopImmediatePropagation();e.preventDefault()}} size="small" /> elements
        </Button>
      };

      function App() {
        return (<>
          <h1>Planning</h1>
          <AddElements/>
        </>)
      };

      const container = document.getElementById('planning');
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
      root.render(
          <App />
      )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```